# How to center a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, center

I am trying to center a button in Javascript so that it is horizontally centered in the page. Right now, my button is in a  in my html file, so I don't know how I can use CSS to center it since it's in Javascript.

TLDR: In Javascript, if I hvae declared a button btn, what code should I write to center it horizontally?

I have searched all over the internet for a way to use Javascript to center a button to no avail. I hope you all can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Why you don't want to do this using css? What is reason to do it using JavaScript?

Comment: It's a lot easier using CSS, refer to https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp for information on how to use CSS.

Comment: Yeah I know how to do it in CSS but the specific way I'm writing my code results in me having to do this in the script tag :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to center an already created button, it could work something like this:

```
<!--In only HTML-->
<button style="position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);">Click Me</button>
```

Another way to do it is to set an id to the button and then center it in a separate CSS file or in the <style> tag like so:

```
<!--HTML-->
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
```

```
/*  
  CSS 
  Remember to use a # before the name because it's an id you're trying to reach
*/
#myButton {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Or you could use JavaScript with the same HTML base

```
<!--HTML-->
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
```

And then in a separate JavaScript file or in the <script> tag

```
// Javascript
let myButton = document.querySelector("#myButton");  myButton.style.position = "absolute";
myButton.style.left = "50%";
myButton.style.transform = "translateX(-50%)";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! StackOverflow won't let me upvote this, but I just wanted you to know how grateful I am :) Have a good day!

Comment: Yes I know that, I'm just happy that I could help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [CSS DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) to achieve it in javascript

you can use the `style` keyword to style an element

for example if you have this code to center the button in css

```html
<div id="div">
  <button>hi</button
</div>
```

```css
div{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
```

you can write it in javascript as

```js
const div = document.getELementById("div");
div.style.display = "flex";
div.style.alignItems = "center";
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways you do to this:

##### Adding style directly in your javascript:

```js
// Create button
var myCenteredButton = document.createElement('button')
myCenteredButton.textContent = 'Here is my centered button'

// Before inserting it to the DOM, add your style
myCenteredButton.style.display = 'block'
myCenteredButton.style.margin = '0 auto'

// Insert to DOM
document.body.append(myCenteredButton)
```

##### Adding a class and letting css style it:

```js
// Create button
var myCenteredButton = document.createElement('button')
myCenteredButton.textContent = 'Here is my centered button'

// Before inserting it to the DOM, add a class for styling with css
myCenteredButton.classList.add('center-me')

// Insert to DOM
document.body.append(myCenteredButton)
```

```css
.center-me {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```